# Several box control in the html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to control several boxes in the HTML. 
[image]

The picture is made by bootstrap library. 
I want If I add more boxes, the boxes is located flexible.

My bootstrap library code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-danger"> New Users </h4>
          <h4 class="text-danger">New Users<span class="label label-danger pull-right">- 9%</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 3%</span> Returning </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-primary"><span class="label label-primary pull-right">201</span> Sales </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 24%</span> Pageviews </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 24%</span> Pageviews </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 24%</span> Pageviews </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 24%</span> Pageviews </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 24%</span> Pageviews </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4 class="text-success"><span class="label label-success pull-right">+ 24%</span> Pageviews </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/row-->    
  </div><!--/col-12-->
</div><!--/row-->

</body>
</html>
```

Who know that's solution?  or Useful libraries?

Comment: *"I want to control several boxes"*, please explain. I don't know what you are wanting to do.

Comment: what kind of control , you want !!!

Comment: You can want javascript library "Match height" for every `<div class="col-md-3"` or in CSS add rules `div.col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {clear: left}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Steps as mentioned in below tutorial

https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/

Because it is applied in bootstrap layout with responsiveness.

Comment: Wow.. That's too great. I don't know bootstrap lib has the function. That's very useful. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), this library is good for placing boxes on the page.

Comment: Thanks so much ! That's solution I want. Isotope lib is so great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
max=-1
$('.col-md-3 .well').each(function(index,i){
h=$(i).css('height').match(/\d+/g)[0]
        console.log(h)
if(h>max)
{
max=h
}
})
$('.col-md-3 .well').css('height',h+'px')
```